# How to locate scrapyd logs file on Linux server？

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

The logs file generated by scrapyd occupies too much memory. I want to find it and delete it. How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

as per scrapyd documentation, the logs should be located in 
`/var/log/scrapyd/` 
 
 the main log file `/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.log`

there are other two logs which log console output and error

`/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.out` 
`/var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.err`

there will be individual logs for each project
 `/var/log/scrapyd/PROJECT/SPIDER/ID.log` 

 you can delete the logs using `rm` command 

but I suggest you implement log rotate  [link](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) instead of deleting the logs manually

Comment: I am wondering if this is still valid in 2021. The folder exists on my ubuntu 20.04 machine but is empty.

Answer (score 1):

They are in the directory which you have specified in [logs_dir](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#logs-dir)

Or get the name of that log file and run

```
find / -name "name_of_file.log"
```